# Creating a measure totalling different columns depending on date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a bar graph visualisation that monitors incoming calls to a call centre by month. Usually, the incoming calls are in the column "s_offered".  Due to factors outside my control, any calls received after 2020-07-01 need to be taken from different column "m_adj_offered".

I have a measure to return a boolean if the date is before the above date

```
m_useadjfigure = if(MIN('Calendar'[Date]) < date(2020,07,01), 0, 1)
```

I then use the below measure in my visualization which is working fine.

```
m_magic_entered = if(QueueSummary[m_useadjfigure] = 1, sum(QueueSummary[m_adj_offered]), sum(QueueSummary[s_offered]))
```

However there is a total in the image which uses the same measure. **The months in the visualization are correct.** But the sum of all the months does not match the total at the top. I understand why this is happening, because of the m_useadjfigure measure condition and the MIN function. But i am not really sure how i could fix it or how i could rewrite the measure (or write a new one).

The report is dynamic with other years available in a slicer so i cannot apply page-level filters etc.

[image: visualization]

In summary, the months on the visualisation are fine. the Total is not.  Can anybody offer some DAX suggestions on how to write a measure to calculate the total correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I will suggest to you is a simple way to resolve your problem and calculate the m_magic_entered measure.

Use this code:

```
m_magic_entered =  
VAR datebar=date(2020,07,01)
RETURN  CALCULATE(sum(QueueSummary[m_adj_offered]),FILTER('Calendar','Calendar'[Date] < datebar) + 
CALCULATE(sum(QueueSummary[s_offered]),FILTER('Calendar','Calendar'[Date] >= 
        datebar)
```

You no longer need m_useadjfigure measure.

Comment: I see where you're going with this but it won't work because post 2020-07-01 there is still data in the s_offered column, but we will just ignore it.

Comment: Thank you - i'm receiving an error "A function MIN has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed."

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. I have taken what you stated and used FILTER rather than MIN etc.

m_magic_entered = CALCULATE(SUM(QueueSummary[s_offered]), FILTER(QueueSummary,[date] < date(2020,07,01))) + CALCULATE(SUM(QueueSummary[m_adj_offered]), FILTER(QueueSummary,[date] >= date(2020,07,01)))